# No space for OutlinedBox TextInputLayout label

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

The outline for an `OutlinedBox TextInputLayout` doesnt leave a space for the hint/label:

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edit_title_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Playlist Name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTextInputLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="60"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<style name="CustomTextInputLayout" parent="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dialog_text_color</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/dialog_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:padding">15dp</item>
</style>
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md#outlined-text-field) says to set the `android:hint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could stem from the padding added to TextInputLayout (15dp), which would interfere with the hint/label.

You could also add padding to the first TextInputLayout in your code using android::paddingTop="15dp" (and/or paddingStart/paddingEnd) to make space for the label.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I'll need to add the padding to a layout around the `TextInputLayout`. Thanks